# Loading forever on start up "attempting repairs" screen on Acer laptop

Tags: boot, windows-11, bootrepair

Since I couldn't update my windows without getting a "retry" condition, I followed up with some YT videos and tried a fix. After restarting the laptop, windows didn't load, rather it tried to repair. Now, it is almost two hours and still "attempting repairs" screen is loading. I'm using windows 11. Much appreciated it if someone can help with this.

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate what "fix" you attempted exactly.  You should be as specific as possible in your description of what you did. However, in most cases, when Windows cannot update, it indicates a larger problem.  In your case it appears the storage device might be failing, since Windows is attempting to repair system files, given it's been 2 hours it's likely ran into a problem it cannot resolve.

Comment: @Ramhound what should I do now?

Comment: @Lucifer you should do what Ramhound asked. We need to know HOW you broke the system before we can suggest how you fix it.